# Dictionary without Case structure

Tags: labview

Is there any way of creating in LabVIEW something like a dictionary known from many other programming languages like C#, python, C++ (Map) without use of case structure ?

Comment: Just curious, what was it about the case structure that you wanted to avoid?

Comment: when you don't know about things like variants or OpenG libs (that came as answers), obvious way, to get something like a Dictionary is to use Case structure with selector for each key, that I wanted to use in a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OpenG library is pretty old. Another alternative is to use variant attributes directly, which should also be more efficient:

[image: Variant attribute lookup]

As long as you use the same variant, the attributes will be available.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this solution.

Comment: I don't think this was documented anywhere officially, but it is decently well known. The code is supposed to use a red/black tree algorithm to sort and retrieve the names, which makes manipulating and searching relatively efficient.

There is one thing to be aware of - up to LV 2009 there was a big performance bug if you used a free standing feedback node to hold the variant and wired an empty variant into its init terminal. This was resolved in later versions, but can also be worked around by initializing the variant using a case structure with a first call primitive.

Comment: I really wish they would actually make dictionaries a primary type. The variant stuff works but it's clunky and lacks any type enforcement.

Comment: If you want to enforce a specific type, simply wrap the call in a VI with a specific type as the input. This can also make the API simpler, because then you can hide the variant entirely, effectively turning it into a global table (or you can stay with the variant as an input, or you can use a DVR to make it by-ref).

Answer (score 4):

In the OpenG libraries you can find the Dictionary library. Install it with [VI Package manager](http://jki.net/vipm) (comes with LabVIEW 2012, to be downloaded for previous LabVIEW versions).

A bit difficult to use since it uses variants, but here's an example to start with:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You gave me what I've asked for, but decided to use basic solution, available in pure LV, because it works the same way (when you look at the code).